# How to create custom block in wordpress 5.1

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to create custom Block in wordpress 5.1. Block like simple text block. I want to add different style for this block that's why create new block

Comment: what is your main goal, and what you want to do, there is many plugin and feature that you can use!

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/) yet? If so, what have you tried so far? Are you having issues with something in particular?

Comment: @nasser I want to add section called see also. For that section i need to add title and need to link that line another post this is my main goal. after that i can style that section according to my theme

Comment: Hello new contributor! You need to come with more effort to this platform. Your question lacks of information. You could give us a sample, or a picture, or something that show you have done something for your question. Please try again.